# Nice Audio Mixer/Repeater

Tags: audio

I am looking for a nice volume mixer for OS-X Yosemite+ for per-application audio control, I would also like per application sound output control.
I don't mind buying if it's a nice product with long term support.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on the "nice" part? What does "nice" mean to you?

Comment: It means functional, supported, non-glitchy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Soundflower](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) from Cycling74 used to be the app to do this type of task, but is unsupported & no longer reliable - I eventually had to uninstall it.

It was taken over by Rogue Amoeba, who maintain the download but no longer provide updates. It has been open sourced on [GitHub](https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower), but I've yet to see a stable release; kernel panics are frequent.

It seems quite possible they re-worked the technology into their main product, [Audio Hijack](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/). Although primarily marketed as an 'any app' recorder, it actually can achieve some pretty comprehensive routing; comes with a fair number of built-in audio effects & can also use any AU plugin effects too.

This is a quick example, using 2 apps, EQ, volume, optional recorder & a specific audio output.

[image]

...and another with 3 sources to 3 outputs...

[image]

If you need even more comprehensive routing, there's always [Plogue Bidule](https://www.plogue.com/products/bidule/)... if you can ever figure it out ;-)

Comment: Cool! Does audio hijack suffer from frequent instability/kernel panics as well?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera I use both frequently for pro audio applications and have never had an issue with either of them. Great tools.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was going to suggest the same. Also I appreciate how you used screencap images to illustrate. +1

Comment: [sorry, was afk a couple of days] I've never had Audio Hijack give me any problems at all - though most of the work I do is over ASIO or Rewire, so I don't use it a great deal. Bidule I only ever tried out a demo for a few days, never really got to grips with it & didn't proceed with it, so can't really comment on that one. @tjt263 - thanks for the comments & upvote :)