# Route the Audio Output to Input (not creating loop)

Tags: itunes, audio, music, skype, logic

Can we have whatever music we are playing whether from spotify, logic, itunes, instead of coming out of the main output, be a part of what goes in to the input on e.g. logic or skype.  This would allow people to listen to music together without going through speakers and mics, and to record to logic without having to upload a song file, e.g. the main output would be one track and the mic would be another, for a little two track action.  But on the skype side, you could turn the music vs. mic volume up or down to hear more of one vs the other.  It seems like this should be possible, but execution is way out of my league.  Anybody think it's doable?

Comment: Audio Hijack - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/203009/85275

Answer (score 1):

Use either [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/), [SoundFlower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/), or [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/).