# Split Input Channels Using SoundFlower and AULab

Tags: audio

I want to split my stereo input channels so I can Eq one of them. They both would then go to the built-in output. I've installed SoundFloser and AU Lab on Mac OS 10.12 Sierra. I've read through the help pages for AU lab. I couldn't find anything specific to my need. With all the options, it looks like it should be possible. I've tried selecting two mono inputs. I get two left channels as input. I didn't see any way to change the source of the mono input, but I could have missed it.

Comment: It must be done in SoundDkower and AU Lab? Anything else an option (GarageBand, premiere, audition, Logic)?

Comment: I'm not picky about the method. AU Lab was the first I found. I just want to adjust one channel's output to my headphone to help with a hearing loss. The only input I really care about is from iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done using Rogue Amoeba's [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) which is ostensibly an audio recorder but has really comprehensive routing capabilities too.

You build your path just by drag & drop, it makes the connections for you.

Route a source to two different Channels plugins, kill left in one & kill right in the other - that way each will pass only a single side of the stereo pair.
In front of that you put two EQ plugins, then route both to a single output, headphones/speakers etc.

[image]

It's fairly expensive for a one-trick pony, but it's extremely useful if you need the trick it can do.

I posted more examples on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/203009/85275

BTW, remember to switch it on once you've built it ;-) Button bottom left goes white & the numbers go orange & start to count time.
As a side-effect, launching any specific Hijack preset will launch any apps assigned to it.

Comment: I'm not going this route, but it is an answer to the question.

Comment: After spending hours trying to find a way to get AU Lab to work, I gave Audio Hijack a try. It was real easy to set up and did what I wanted. I did have to pay $50 for the application. If you have normal hearing Soundflower and AU Lab should be fine.

Comment: Glad you got your solution - as I said, one-trick-pony, but it's a very well-crafted one trick.

Comment: And is there something simpler? Basically controlling L-R balance for individual app is enough. By the way, Audio Hijack has small latency, which is noticeable when making something realtime.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can split stereo input with [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) and [AU Lab](https://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/) and apply an effect on one channel only.

1. Set *Soundflower* as mac audio output,
2. create a new document in *AU Lab*,
3. add another *Audio Input…* ⇧⌘A,
4. double click on first (left) input track, change *Input Channels* to mono and confirm,
5. adjust accordingly second (right) input track, remember to drag the brown bar to the right cell in the compartment labeled *Soundflower Input Stream #1*,
6. turn *Panner* knobs full left/right on respective input tracks,
7. apply the desired effect on the track of your choice,
8. configure *Output Settings* in *Studio* ⇧⌘I if necessary.

---

AU Lab with split channels and Equalizer effect applied to the right channel only:

[image: AU Lab with split channels and Equalizer effect applied to the right channel only]

[image: right channel input conifguration]

Answer (score 0):

For everyone here not able to make AU Lab run on Catalina:

Just put AU Lab to the Application folder, and manually edit the TCC trust database:

```
sudo sqlite3 /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "insert into access VALUES('kTCCServiceMicrophone','com.apple.audio.aulab',0,1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UNUSED',NULL,0,1541440109) ;"
```