# Compressor Plugin for Audio Output of Mac

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume, movie

When listening to audio or watching a video clip on a Mac, I sometimes wish for a more even sound level throughout the playback, i.e. less variation in volume. Is there a way to compress the output audio (preferably at OS level) from my Mac? Any applications, plug-ins, etc.?

Comment: [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) is the go-to app for anything like this. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203004/nice-audio-mixer-repeater/203009#203009 & http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271164/split-input-channels-using-soundflower-and-aulab/271194#271194 for some idea of what it's capabilities are.

Comment: thanks, Audio Hijack seems to be indeed very powerful! But is there maybe a less functional, free of charge tool/app?

Comment: None that I know of. SoundFlower is/was the tool for routing, but it doesn't have any plugin structure to add the actual compressor