# Combine two input sources to one input source?

Tags: audio, microphone, input-source, soundflower

Can I use soundflower and my microphone together at the same time?

Example usage: stream desktop audio through Skype, while still being able to talk to the person simultaneously.

I wonder if aggregate sound devices may be able to accomplish this, but I haven't found a way.

---

I've tried making an aggregate device, and simply checking the 2 devices:

[image]

However, it only "broadcasts" the first device I checked; if I click the microphone first, then I can only hear the microphone through this device, and if I click soundflower first, I can only hear soundflower.

Comment: @Allan I've already tried this, "but I haven't found a way." I can edit into my question more specifically what I've already tried.

Comment: The go-to app for anything like this is [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) [£$€ 50 ish]  see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/274103/85275 https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271194/85275 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/203009/85275 for some example routings. There really is nothing at all to touch it.