# Change safari input device (microphone)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, microphone, input-source

I was trying to use this website: https://guitar-tuner.appspot.com

But it wasn't working at all even after I allowed it access to the microphone.

I suspected this may be to do with me having six different "microphones" (input sources—I have both soundflowers, a device for my TV, and a bunch of virtual ones from Loopback)

I thought maybe Safari was using the wrong microphone, so I went to these two sites to check that and neither worked (they didn't even prompt for microphone access):

- https://www.onlinemictest.com/
- https://www.onlinemictest.com/microphone-settings/mac-os-x/

Comment: Are you sure Soundflower & Loopback won't fight each other?

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah I've had both installed now for three months at least without any problem

Comment: I gave up on Soundflower altogether at about Mavericks, tbh. It got very crashy. I usually route with Audio Hijack, which suits my visual sense. Loopback I have but haven't yet really found a good use for - it kind of has a bunch of 'hidden' setups in the app itself & I'm not sure how you would route one input to a given app with it... that's more an audio hijack job.

Comment: Some 'demo' routings from Audio Hijack, so you can see what I mean - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203004/nice-audio-mixer-repeater/203009#203009 also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271164/split-input-channels-using-soundflower-and-aulab/271194#271194 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274090/mono-output-from-an-external-dac/274103#274103