# How to use audio impulse response filters / digital signal processing in macOS?

Tags: audio, plugins

I've used Room EQ Wizard to generate impulse response filters. These filters can be loaded into a Digital Signal Processor which will then correct the audio signal according to the speaker and room acoustics.

I'm using these filters with [Shairport-Sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync/issues/1174) on a Raspberry Pi and they work really really well.

I want to also use them with my Mac, but I haven't found a way to do it yet. What I'm hoping for is that there is some piece of software that can read in the audio stream, apply the filter and then output it seamlessly - whether that be some sort of plugin for macOS itself, or whether it means routing audio through a software processor using something like [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole).

Comment: This link - https://audiophilestyle.com/forums/topic/18148-room-correction-on-os-x-thread/ - with some bickering & misinterpretation, just about covers the state of play on Mac at least pre-Catalina. tbh, unless you're working only to stereo, it's all a bit hand wavy because the Mac does not process 5.1 internally, so you can't intercept it to perform transformations/compression/EQ etc. Personally, as I trust my ears a whole lot more than I do some uncalibrated automatic system I just lined up a couple of multiband comps & everything is lovely.

Comment: The simple consumer solution for this is [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) & I linked to some others on here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411157/85275 I don't know of anything at consumer level that does convolution in that way. If you've got a spare €500 I know some good pro stuff, though it still won't work on a pre-compiled movie 5.1 soundtrack, only raw source ;))

Comment: More background on Mac output only being handled as stereo - https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/45949/9601

Comment: Hmm… this looks interesting… https://www.jriver.com/audio.html

Comment: @Tetsujin jriver seems to be a media manager. Not really useful to me as I want to apply DSP to sound from any app.

Comment: Then you're back to SoundSource or something else that can intercept the output with plugins. I looked at JRiver because it appears to be able to use convolution. I've never seen anything else that can.