# How to control L/R audio balance for apps separately?

Tags: audio

I'm trying to set a L/R balance for various apps separately. For example, one app would play through the left channel and the other would be set to the right. I haven't yet found a solution to do so, besides changing the settings globally, which is not exactly what I want.

Is there a way to go about it? I'd appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: This is going to be yet another plug from me for [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271164/split-input-channels-using-soundflower-and-aulab/271194#271194 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203004/nice-audio-mixer-repeater/203009#203009 for examples.