# Is there an Apple AudioUnit plugin that provides a different EQ for each channel?

Tags: audio

I'm using [SoundSource](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) to allow myself finer control about my audio, including EQs and different output devices for different apps.

I also discovered that I can add Apple's preinstalled AU plugins to the mixer:

[image: AU effect selection in SoundSource]

I would like to know if there is any AU plugin on the market that provides an individual EQ for each channel (left and right, stereo) that I can install and use in SoundSource, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a multi-channel AU/VST plugin which SoundSource can use.
I've no idea how good  or flexible it is, so give it a try. It claims to be multi-channel but I can't tell from the description whether these can be configured truly independently.
[Voxengo Overtone GEQ](https://www.voxengo.com/product/overtonegeq/)
The 'problem' with EQing L/R separately - & why it's less likely to crop up in 'pro' audio editors - is that EQ changes phase*; so changing phase on each side of a stereo image can produce slightly odd results.

I [answered a question on here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271194/85275) once, a while back, on how to do something similar, but it was using Audio Hijack [SoundSource's older brother] & contains it own plugins which can split left & right [they're not installed as AUs, they're definitely internal to the app… I tried before;)
There's another answer underneath using Soundflower & AU Lab, but I stopped using those years ago & don't know if they still work on newer OSes.

*It doesn't always & can be partially avoided, but that's an entire university dissertation;)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the [Voxengo Overtone GEQ](https://www.voxengo.com/product/overtonegeq/)  was the way to go. If you edit your answer linking to it, I will mark it as accepted answer. Btw, yes, I remember those days using Soundflower & AU Lab as well. It was a mess compared to SoundSource, really amazed by this piece of software. I think Soundflower won't run on BigSur anyways.

Comment: Link changed. tbh, I haven't used Soundflower since it first started getting flaky at maybe Mavericks or so. I've had Audio Hijack on every Mac since, Loopback for some more advanced routing, but I now have SoundSource on all the 'consumer' Macs here, including my HTPC, on which I use a multi-band comp to stop the explosions bending the walls whilst still being able to hear speech:)