# iphone app for equalizing left and right channel separately?

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, accessibility

I’m looking for an iphone app that will let me equalize 7 or 8 bands, but with a separate equalizer for each of the left and right sides.

Why? For individuals who have compromised hearing in one ear, hearing aids are designed to boost the amplitude at different frequencies (the “boost” is typically programmed by an audiologist). Basically, custom equalizing for each ear.

However, for streaming services, especially ones that have left and right audio channels, that are intended to be used with headphones, I haven’t found a way to boost, for example, the higher frequencies in the right ear by various db levels.

This doesn’t seem like a hard thing to implement. Many iphone apps feature an 8 band equalizer, but the equalization is sent to both the left and right channels equally. Seems like two equalizers, one for left, and one for right, would do the trick.

For example, an application that could stream separately equalized left and right channels from an iphone 12-mini to a Bose noise cancelling headphone would be representative.

Cheers,
-Bruce

PS: For what it’s worth, information wise, here are two sets of bands that might be useful (either one). The audiology set (based on 250 Hz) would probably be best, since this set is used in audiology testing. Again, what I’m looking for is an app that will let me equalize each ear separately, at either of these sets of frequencies.

- 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000 Hz (standard audiology frequencies)
- 110, 220, 440, 880, 1760, 3520, 7040 Hz (musician oriented, eg A-440 as a base)

PPS: The attached image is an audiogram (generated during a standard audiology test). For individuals with normal hearing, each of these standard pitches are first audible at 20 db. For this individual, hearing in the right ear (in red) is significantly compromised. For example, to hear a pitch at 2000 Hz, the volume has to be boosted to 40 db, and at 4000 Hz, to 75 db.

[image]

Comment: It's possible on Mac, idk about iPhone etc - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271164/split-input-channels-using-soundflower-and-aulab/271194#271194

Comment: Thanks for this. I’ve looked into a similar approach using PCs and digital audio workstation software. Can be made to work, although unwieldy for a streaming plugin in the PC world. Looks like it’s a little better in the mac world. Would really like a simple iphone solution, still looking for it. Thanks.

Comment: I only just looked at your numbers in the graph. Even if you find something with independent L/R EQ, finding one with 75dB boost is going to be highly specialist territory. [It's also going to have to massively reduce the overall volume to compensate. That amount of boost is going to hard red-line most use-cases.] It wouldn't surprise me if 75dB was approaching the useable dynamic range of many things, in practise.